# Rate limiting detection using Stream Java API client

Tags: java, getstream-io

The Stream documentation https://getstream.io/docs/#rate-limiting mentions that

> you will need to review responses from Stream to watch for error
>   conditions indicating that your API request was rate-limited and retry

I'm using the Stream Java API client.
What error conditions do I need to check in order to determine if my API request was rate limited?

Is it an attribute in `StreamClientException` that I need to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's indeed an attribute of `StreamClientException` which contains the returning HTTP status code (i.e. just invoke the method `getHttpStatusCode()`) however, in this case, it won't help since the error code is not propagated.

Thanks to your reporting, we've [fixed the exception handling](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-java/releases/tag/stream-java-1.3.4) to raise the HTTP status code up and, in particular for your use-case, we've introduced a new exception [RateLimitExceededException](https://getstream.github.io/stream-java/io/getstream/client/exception/RateLimitExceededException.html).